# mysql balance query by database name

Tags: mysql, proxy, lua, load-balancing

I have mysql master and some slaves (let us say it 10).
Each slave has own database (pro_mysql_database1, pro_mysql_database2...) and it is not a sharding.

I need some daemon, which will listen on port 3306, parse queries and send all queries about pro_mysql_database1 to slave1, pro_mysql_database1 to slave2 and so on.

I have tried already:

- mysql-proxy - lua scripts can not help, cause during query analyzer it is impossible to change slave behind from LUA.
- spockproxy - for for mysql, which supports sharding by table name, not by database.
- sqlrelay - has own protocol, which not allowed use normal mysql-client.